# Why are the Schwarzchild or Eddington-Finkelstein not maximal?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

In the book by d'Inverno, he writes the definition of a manifold being maximal as 
"A manifold endowed with an affine or metric geometry is said to be maximal if every geodesic emanating from an arbitrary point of the manifold either can be extended to infinite values of the affine parameter along the geodesic in both directions or terminates on an intrinsic singularity."

and then he goes forward to claim that Schwarzchild and Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates are not maximal. I can't seem to think of a reason or a point in spacetime for which the definition of the maximal is violated.

Answer (score 4):

Given definition tells you that maximality is property of manifold, yet you ask about maximality of coordinates. So I will assume you are asking about maximality of manifold defined by one of the coordinate patches.

Typically when you seek spherically symmetrical vacuum solution to Einstein's equations, you define Schwarschild coordinates and seek solution in these coordinates. You get some and you will find there are singularities at $r=2M$ and $r=0$. So you can define 2 manifolds given by $0<r<2M$ or $r>2M$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}, 0\le\phi< 2\pi, 0\le\theta<\pi$. Now, you can ask if these manifolds are maximal as in your definition. Quickly you will see they are not. **F.e. radially infalling particle reaches $r=2M$ and $r=0$ at finite amount of proper time (so the geodesic ends with finite amount of affine parameter)**. The $r=0$ is intrinsic singularity, but $r=2M$ is not and the manifolds you defined can be extended, f.e. by gluing these two parts together (and thus you know that resulted extended manifold is still solution to Einstein's equations) using Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates and you can repeat the whole process with these new coordinates.

Comment: @safesphere So what what will happen to me if i choose to take a spaceship and reach this r=2M before i die? Will i be just sitting there waiting?

Comment: @safesphere Well there is the difference that GR breaks at singularity and is no longer applicable, which is not the case for $r=2M$ - especially for massive black holes. The continuity at this border is logical consequence of equivalence principle, unless there is something nontrivial going on, like black hole firewall.

Comment: @safesphere metric does not diverge at $r=2M$. Metric is defined as bilinear map on tangent space of the manifold and this map has well behaved limit on the horizon. Anyway, I see you saying this thing everywhere on this page and I am curious if you can back it up by some sources in literature?

Comment: @safesphere Those articles look like nonsense. I read the part about BH being closed and there is obvious fault in their reasoning by restricting themselves on the spacelike hypersurface of their own choosing only. That nothing can pass through $r=2M$ of this family of hypersurfaces is actualy trivially visible from penrose diagram as is trivially visible that the fault lies in choosing badly behaved family of hypersurfaces. Do you have any another sources?